# Authentication in Enterprise applications

Tags: membership

I am wondering if anyone has faced a similar issue. We are working on enterprise client portal that would be sitting on the internet. We also would like to add managements/client services portal that would be sitting on the local network and would use the same core libraries. For the external clients we would like to use forms authentication and for the internal application we would like to use windows authentication. Right now we are leaning to use sql membership provider on the external site and active directory membership provider on the internal site. We are working with mvc 4 so we use claims principal throughout the app.

The questions are:
1. Is there a way to combine users so we can enforce username uniqueness using existing providers?
2. We are considering using user email as the key. Is this a security issue. Can I get user email from AD membership provider?

I have looked into simplemembership provider. I thought that I could utilize webpages_OAuthMembership table to store "LDAP" users. But there is no oauth provider for that so I would have to write our own.

On another hand it seems that simplemembership is just a temporary solution until ASPNET.Identity come out in Nov.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Windows Identity Federation (WIF), ASP.NET Identity, MVC5?

All your cases can be implemented using above.